# how to add data in Table of Jasper Report using Java

Tags: java, mysql, jasper-reports

I am trying to pass data to a JasperReport using Java.  However, the table data is very dynamic and I cannot pass the SQL query to the report. Any idea for this?
I have a 2D array of **object** type, where I have all the data. How can I pass that?

```
ConnectionManager con = new ConnectionManager();
    con.establishConnection();

    String fileName = "Pmc_Bill.jrxml";
    String outFileName = "OutputReport.pdf";
    HashMap params  = new HashMap();
    params.put("PName", pname);
    params.put("PSerial", psrl);
    params.put("PGender",pgen);
    params.put("PPhone",pph);
    params.put("PAge",page);
    params.put("PRefer",pref);
    params.put("PDateR",dateNow);
    try {

        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(fileName);

        if(jasperReport != null )
           System.out.println("so far so good ");

        // Fill the report using an empty data source

        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, new JRTableModelDataSource(tbl.getModel()));//con.connection);
        try{
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, outFileName);
        System.out.printf("File exported sucessfully");
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint);
    } catch (JRException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the table data is very dynamic thats y cannot pass sql query"? You'll need a query anyway if your data stays in a database.

Comment: You can read [Data Source Sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/datasource/index.html#datasources) post. The ***JRMapArrayDataSource***, ***JRMapCollectionDataSource***, ***ListOfArrayDataSource***, ***JRBeanArrayDataSource***, ***JRBeanCollectionDataSource*** implementation of datasource are good candidates for your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanColDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dataList);
Map parameters = new HashMap();
parameters.put("ParameterName", "Value Wanna Pass");
parameters.put("Other Parameter", Data source Name For Filling the table);

        JasperReport report = (JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObject("Path for the Jasper");
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());
```